# How to stop an .each .animate loop function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-animate, each

I try to move a set of different `div`, to do that I did a `function` to make an infinite movement in the space. Now I want to put the different `div` in a sort of grid to class them. It runs sometimes but It don't stop the `function` and when every divs are placed it continue to move.
What I wan't (without using a library like Particle.js) is to make it move continually but when I click, it instantly stop the div and run from their position to the grid, and on the second click, it go from the grid to the function.

[I write it on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Fromager/vc0u3omz/)

Here is the Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function move() {
    $('div').each(function(){
      var top = $(this).css('top');
      var left = $(this).css('left');
      var topEnd = $(this).data('top-end');
      var leftEnd = $(this).data('left-end');
      $(this).animate({
          left: leftEnd,
          top: topEnd
      }, 3000).animate({
          left: left,
          top: top
      }, 3000,move);
     }
)}
move();

$('button').click(function(){
  $('div').each(function(){
            var position = $(this).position();
    var gridTop = $(this).data('grid-top');
    var gridLeft = $(this).data('grid-left');
    var topEnd = $(this).data('top-end');
    var leftEnd = $(this).data('left-end');
    if(position.top == gridTop ){
      $(this).animate({
        left: leftEnd,
        top: topEnd
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      $(this).animate({
        left: gridLeft,
        top: gridTop
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
});
```

});

And here the html :

```
<button>click moi</button>
<div data-grid-left="10px" data-grid-top="130px" data-left-end="250px" data-top-end="250px" style="background:green;left:-50px;"></div>
<div data-grid-left="130px" data-grid-top="10px" data-left-end="350px" data-top-end="-50px" style="background:red;top:200px;left:-200px;"></div>
<div data-grid-left="130px" data-grid-top="130px" data-left-end="500px" data-top-end="100px" style="background:blue;top:400px;left:-100px;"></div>
```

Comment: add .stop() to end

Comment: yes... I just found it

Answer (score 0):

You can add .stop() at the end of

`$('button').click(function(){ 
...`

Comment: I test it like that [https://jsfiddle.net/Fromager/vc0u3omz/](https://jsfiddle.net/Fromager/vc0u3omz/) but it doesn't really run